# Дед до полупьяна / дополупьяна буйствовал

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Дед до полупьяна / дополупьяна буйствовал, а потом начал веселиться.`

Comment: Узнаватель нового о русском языке, говорите? Надо бы притормозить, т.е. о традиционной сочетаимости почитать.

Comment: Ну да, ну да... В чужом глазу... О *сочета**е**мости*, наверное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве версии:

*Дед **до полупьяна** буйствовал, а потом начал веселиться.*

Сравнить: *Штаб-ротмистр повиновался и крепко заснул; в это время Тимошка, с радости, напился **до полусмерти**.*

Разные варианты встречаются (до чего? и как?).  Наречное выражение и наречие.

**Раздельное написание**

*За ужином, в офицерской кают-компании, хвастовство его не имело границ, и когда **он напился до полупьяна**, мои три человека были произведены им в полную команду брига, на котором находилось столько людей и пушек, сколько на бриге и поместиться не может!* Фредерик Марриет, Морской офицер Франк Мильдмей, 1829.

*У нашего царя Петра Михайлыча заводился бал. **До полусыта наедались, до полупьяна напивались.** Стал бал навеселе.*

*Песня: Евген Кириллов. **До полупьяна.***

Евгений Сокольских. Сонет.  ***До полупьяна** начитавшись Мандельштама...*

Comment: Мне просто не нравится, что в правилах-то написано, что мы предлоги с прилагательными, наречия образуя, пишем слитно, а *полупьяный* — прилагательное. А *полусмерть* — это сущ., а с существительными мы *до*, например *до смерти*, раздельно пишем, так что это плохое сравнение.

Comment: Это да, но исключения возможны. К предлогам БЕЗ и ДО вообще особое отношение.  Для данной группы слов факт наличия падежного управления имеет преимущественное значение, поэтому некоторые из них пишутся раздельно, несмотря на то что не употребляются без предлога: до зарезу, до упаду, без прОсыпа, без ведома, без продыху. Пользователи склоняются к раздельной форме.

Answer (score 1):

В Википедии написано так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следовательно, в значении наполовину полного опъянения тоже слитно — *дополупьяна*.

*Дед дополупьяна (= до наполовину полного опъянения) буйствовал, а потом начал веселиться.*

Плюс ссылка: https://kak-pravilno.net/dopyana-ili-do-pyana-kak-pravilno/.